# Axios with Express "Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm a new developer trying to understand routers and controllers with Express, Express Router, and Axios.

server (app.js):

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');

var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var authRouter = require('./routes/auth');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/login', authRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

router (auth.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const controller = require("../controllers/auth.controller");

router.post('/login', controller.login);

module.exports = router;
```

controller (auth.controller.js):

```
var axios = require('axios');

const url = "https://my-api-url.com";

module.exports = {
    login: (req, res) => {
        console.log('made login request');
        return axios.post(url + "/token", {
            username: req.body.username, 
            password: req.body.password
            }, {
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            }).then((response) => {
                res.send({
                    access_token: response.data.access_token
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('failed to login');
        });
    }
};
```

I receive a "POST localhost 404 (Not Found)" and "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404" response on the console. However, this works perfectly:

app.js (without router and controller):

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var axios = require('axios');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const url = "https://my-api-url.com";

// returns access token 
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('made login request!');
    axios.post(url + "/token", {username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}, {
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    }).then((response) => {
        res.send({access_token: response.data.access_token});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('failed to login');
    });
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I could just continue using the last code segment since it works perfectly fine, but I want to learn the logic and best practices. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating two seperate routers in your two router files (indexRouter and authRouter)? `express.Router()`

Comment: Yes my indexRouter is the out of the box file from express: var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;

Comment: You are not using in your 2nd code. Two seperate router instances might be causing the problem. Use one router instance and organize your code that way. For starters, you xan comment the indexRouter statement and related code in first code file and check if that works.

Comment: It didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.js`, when you used a router:

`app.use('/login', authRouter);`

Your application will get any route inside your router in relative way.

When inside your router you handle post that way:

`router.post('/login', controller.login);`

Your application will wait a call like this: `http://localhost:3000/login/login/`

If you want to call with `http://localhost:3000/login/`, your router should be like this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const controller = require("../controllers/auth.controller");

router.post('/', controller.login);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Do I use the '/' for every router object? What would be a case when I would change it?

Comment: You can nest a router inside another router. Each router has its own relative path. Here, `router.post('/', controller.login);` waits for `http://localhost:3000/login/`. So, if you would  want `http://localhost:3000/login/password`, in the login router file you would add: `router.post('/password', controller.password);`